# react-native-material-bottom-navigation-how can i change the navigation between the screens

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-material-bottom-navigation` module.How can i change the navigation between the screens using this module.
Here is my code:

```
<BottomNavigation
  labelColor="black"
  backgroundColor="white"
  activeLabelColor='white'
  // rippleColor="white"
  shifting={false}
  // overflow =' hidden'
  style={{ elevation: 8, position: 'absolute', height: 56, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}
  onTabChange={(newTabIndex) => alert(`New Tab at position ${newTabIndex}`)}
>
  <Tab
    barBackgroundColor="black"
    label="Shop"
    labelColor="white"
    activeLabelColor="white"
    icon={<Image source={require('@images/coffeeCupW.png')} color="white" name="Shop" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}
  />
  <Tab
    barBackgroundColor="black"
    label="Cart"
    labelColor="white"
    activeLabelColor="white"
    icon={<Image source={require('@images/shopping-cartW.png')} color="white" name="Cart" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}
  />
  <Tab
    barBackgroundColor="black"
    label="My Orders"
    labelColor="white"
    activeLabelColor="white"
    icon={<Image source={require('@images/ordersW.png')} color="white" name="My Orders" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}
  />
</BottomNavigation>
```

here is my screenshot:

[image]

please give me any suggestion

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of react-native-material-bottom-navigation.*

`react-native-material-bottom-navigation` is just a Component for the Bottom Navigation. It doesn't include functionality to navigate between screens. To put it simply: It's just a bunch of fancy looking Buttons side by side.

**But** it tells you which Tab the user pressed, so you can use it together with libraries for navigation, for example:

- [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/)
- [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)
- [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)
- [NavigatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html#navigatorios) (if you just want to support iOS)

Answer (score 1):

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
import Tab1 from './tab1.js'
import Tab2 from './tab2.js'
import Tab3 from './tab3.js'
import Tab4 from './tab4.js'
import Tab5 from './tab5.js'

export default class GroupScreen extends Component {


 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: 0,
      selectedTab: 'tab1'
   };
    this.handleTabChange = this.handleTabChange.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {

  }
  render() {
  const { state, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        {this.renderTabs()}
         {this.renderFooterView()}

      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

// Components
renderFooterView() {
    return(

    <BottomNavigation
      activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
      rippleColor="white"
      activeLabelColor="white"
      shifting={false}
      style={{ height: 56, elevation: 8, position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}
      onTabChange={this.handleTabChange}>
      <Tab
        barBackgroundColor="white"
        icon={<Image source={assets.Setting.home} color="white" name="Home" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}

      />
      <Tab
        barBackgroundColor="white"
        icon={<Image source={assets.Setting.groupFilled} color="white" 
      name="Group" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}
      />
      <Tab
        barBackgroundColor="white"
        icon={<Image source={assets.Setting.requestLook} color="white" name="Group" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}

      />
      <Tab
        barBackgroundColor="white"
        icon={<Image source={assets.Setting.profile} color="white" name="Group" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}

      />
      <Tab
        barBackgroundColor="white"
        icon={<Image source={assets.Setting.setting} color="white" name="Group" style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />}

      />
    </BottomNavigation>
     )
}

renderTabs() {
  switch (this.state.activeTab) {
    case 0:
      return <Tab1 />
      break
    case 1:
      return <Tab2 />
      break
    case 2:
      return <Tab3 />
      break
    case 3:
      return <Tab4 />
      break
    case 4:
      return <Tab5 />
      break

  }
}
  // Handlers
  handleTabChange(newTabIndex, oldTabIndex) {
   this.setState({ activeTab: newTabIndex });
   if (newTabIndex === oldTabIndex) {
     null;
   }
   if (this.state.activeTab === 0) {
     this.setState({selectedTab: 'tab1',});
   } else if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
     this.setState({selectedTab: 'tab2',});
   } else if (this.state.activeTab === 2) {
     this.setState({selectedTab: 'tab3',});
   }else if(this.state.activeTab==3){
     this.setState({selectedTab: 'tab4',});
   }
   else {
     this.setState({selectedTab: 'tab5',});
   }
 }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different contents on your screen depending on the active tab, you can use the onTabPress prop and save the active tab in your state. Check out the Chapter Controlled Component.

You most likely want to use this together with a navigation library, e.g. React Navigation or React Native Navigation.